# How do you set up a property in a custom gradle task?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, groovy, gradle-task

I want to write a task that takes a directory `from` , does something with the files in it and writes the result into some other directory `to`.

I've been led to believe this was the way to define such a task (kotlin dsl):

```kotlin
package my.app

abstract class FooBarTask : DefaultTask() {

    @get:InputDirectory
    abstract val from: Property<Directory>

    @get:OutputDirectory
    abstract val to: Property<Directory>

    @TaskAction
    fun doSomething() {
        println("Hakuna Matata")
    }
}
```

now how do I set the `from` and `to` value in a groovy-based `build.gradle`?

```
def myTask = tasks.register('myTask', FooBarTask) {
    from = layout.projectDirectory.dir("foo")
    to = layout.buildDirectory.dir("bar")
}
```

this results in

```
Could not create task ':my-subproject:myTask'.
   > Please use the ObjectFactory.directoryProperty() method to create a property of type Directory.
```

and it shouldn't.

How do you correctly define a directory property in a custom task?

Comment: Have you tried using https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/DirectoryProperty.html instead of `Property<Directory>`

Comment: @LeonardBrünings that seems to have done the trick, thank you. if you make an answer out of it, could you briefly explain the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2):

Gradle has the specialized [DirectoryProperty](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/DirectoryProperty.html), that offers some additional functionality, compared to the plain `Property<Directory>` which is one of the implemented interfaces. So this specialized type should be used when declaring directory inputs/outputs.

I'm actually not a 100% sure what caused the error you saw.